count distinct of customers relative to a date
I am trying to find distinct count of transacting client ids prior to the time of a transaction from this table and associate the count to each transaction



transaction id
client id
transaction date




t1
C1
01/01/2024


t2
C2
01/02/2024


t3
C2
01/02/2024


t4
C3
01/03/2024


t5
C1
01/04/2024


t6
C4
01/05/2024



Desired output:



transaction id
client id
transaction date
prior distinct client count




t1
C1
01/01/2024
0


t2
C2
01/02/2024
1


t3
C2
01/02/2024
1


t4
C3
01/03/2024
2


t5
C1
01/04/2024
3


t6
C4
01/05/2024
3



I tried using
select
transaction id,
client id,
transaction date,
count(distinct client id) over (order by transaction date asc rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
from 
<table name>

However,  snowflake does not support an OVER clause that contains an ORDER BY clause for DISTINCT operation in the window function.
I am also trying to avoid self join queries as the transaction table is very large. Any help with alternatives is appreciated.

if you are trying to aggregate over many periods, then you might need to use BITMAP COUNT and friends. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-bitmaps-for-distinct-counts build the bitmap for each day, then agreegate for each window of interest, and then turn that into a count.

Why is the count for t3 1? Shouldn't it be 2, because in t1 and t2 there where 2 different clients? Or is it because you don't want to include t2 because it is the same client as t3 (consecutive rows with the same client)? Or is it because you don't want to include t2 because it is the same client and the same date as t3 (consecutive rows with the same client and date)? Or is there still another reason?

create or replace table transaction_client as     
select 
  column1 as transaction_id, 
  column2 as client_id, 
  column3 as transaction_date 
from 
values 
  ('t1', 'C1', '01/01/2024'), 
  ('t2', 'C2', '01/02/2024'), 
  ('t3', 'C2', '01/02/2024'), 
  ('t4', 'C3', '01/03/2024'), 
  ('t5', 'C1', '01/04/2024'), 
  ('t6', 'C4', '01/05/2024');
  
  
select 
  a.transaction_id, 
  a.client_id, 
  a.transaction_date, 
  count(distinct b.client_id) as prior_distinct_client_count 
from 
  transaction_client a 
  left join transaction_client b 
 on b.transaction_date < a.transaction_date 
group by  a.transaction_id,a.client_id, a.transaction_date 
order by a.transaction_date;


This will work, but the performance will not be optimal with large tables because of the complex WHERE in the subquery.
SELECT transaction_id,
       client_id,
       transaction_date,
       (
           SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t2.client_id)
             FROM #t t2
            WHERE t2.transaction_date < t1.transaction_date
       ) AS prior_distinct_client_count
  FROM #t t1


This may do exactly what you want but I don't have access to a SQL database supporting aggregation windows by RANGE (but SnowFlake has it, as I understand): an idea to would be to mark the first occurrence of each new client and then count the first of them:
select *, count(*) over (partition by clientid order by transactiondate, transactionid) OccOrder
from Mytbl)
select *, 
  count(case when OccOrder=1 then 1 end) over (order by transactiondate range between unbounded preceding and current row)-
  count(case when OccOrder=1 then 1 end) over (order by transactiondate range between current row and current row) as PriorDistinctClientCount
from MarkFirstOcc


I used SQLServer2019 for this, and it has some restrictions for the upper part of the RANGE criteria; hence the subtraction.
Logically this is just one sort and two passes but I wouldn't guess how Snowflake will execute it; it may even choose to do the self-join you wanted to avoid.

If you have access to LATERAL:
select d.*, l.cc
from transaction_client d,
lateral(
    select count(distinct client_id) as cc 
    from transaction_client d1 where d1.transaction_date < d.transaction_date
) l
order by d.transaction_date
;


You can substitute DISTINCT by row_number()over(partition by client_id ...) as rn
and count(distinct client_id) with sum(case when rn=1 then 1 else 0 end)
Coalesce - for first row without precedings.
Note that the order by transaction_date does not unambiguous determine the order of the rows. You need to add a transaction_id to order by.
See example
select transaction_id, client_id, transaction_date
  ,coalesce(sum(case when rn=1 then 1 else 0 end)
    over(order by transaction_date,transaction_id 
         rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding )
   ,0) prior_distinct_client_count
  ,chck, rn
from(
  select *
    ,row_number()over(partition by client_id order by transaction_date,transaction_id)rn
  from transactions
)a




transaction_id
client_id
transaction_date
prior_distinct_client_count
chck
rn




t1
C1
2024-01-01
0
0
1


t2
C2
2024-02-01
1
1
1


t3
C2
2024-02-01
2
1
2


t4
C3
2024-03-01
2
2
1


t5
C1
2024-04-01
3
3
2


t6
C4
2024-05-01
3
3
1



fiddle
Test data:



transaction_id
client_id
transaction_date
chck




t1
C1
2024-01-01
0


t2
C2
2024-02-01
1


t3
C2
2024-02-01
1


t4
C3
2024-03-01
2


t5
C1
2024-04-01
3


t6
C4
2024-05-01
3



I think, query with self join or subquery for every row will be noticeably slower.

Thanks. This worked great!
